# Application always calls onCreate() when the phone is locked and unlocked

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to save the state of the application because the application calls `onCreate()` everytime the android phone is locked. When I unlocked it, the app calls the onCreate() method and start again.. BTW my app is like text twist. When I unlock the screen a new word is shown, instead of the current one.. The score is also reset as well as the time.. How can I work on this? Please help.. It's still unanswered..

This is the whole code of my activity..

```
public class friend extends Activity {

    //score
     ScoreHandler scHandler;
     Score sc;
     int totalScore;

     //words
    //DatabaseHelper dbHelp;
    DBHelper dbHelp;
    public String randomWord;

    //speech
    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;
    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private TextView txtText;

    //shake
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private ShakeEventListener mSensorListener;


    //timer
     private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
        private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
        private TextView timeText;
        private final long startTime = 180 * 1000;
        private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
        private long timeLeft;

        private int gameScore;
        private TextView shuffleView;

        TextView scoreView;


    //Animation
        Animation myFadeInAnimation;
        Animation myFadeOutAnimation;
        Animation leftToRight;


    //sliding
            Button mCloseButton;
            Button mOpenButton;
            MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer mDrawer;

            Context context;

            static final String STATE_SCORE = "currentScore";
            static final String STATE_WORD = "currentWord";

            static final String STATE_TIME = "currentTime";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
             gameScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
            timeLeft = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_TIME);
            randomWord = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_WORD);
        } else {
            // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.friend);

        leftToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right);

        ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextround_game);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(friend.this, friend1.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



        ImageButton giveUp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.surrender_game);

        giveUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(friend.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


      //score



    //timer

        timeText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);

        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        timeText.setText(timeText.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime/1000));


            countDownTimer.start();
            timerHasStarted = true;

        this.removeAll();


         dbHelp = new DBHelper(this);


         randomWord = dbHelp.random();

         System.out.println(randomWord);

         String wordCaps = randomWord.toUpperCase();

         final String finalWord = shuffle(wordCaps);

        shuffleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jumble);


         Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/American Captain.ttf"); 
         shuffleView.setTypeface(type);

        shuffleView.setText(finalWord);




        //shake
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorListener = new ShakeEventListener();   

        mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

            public void onShake() {



            //String str = (String) stringList.remove(selectedWord);




            String wordOutput = shuffle(finalWord);

             TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jumble);

             tv.setText(wordOutput);

            }

        });





        //speech
        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                    txtText.setText("");
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                }
            }
        });


    }



            public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
            public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
                super(startTime, interval);
            }



            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timeText.setText("0:00");
                playSound(R.raw.clock_whistle);

                ImageView timeIsUp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.time_is_up);


                timeIsUp.startAnimation(leftToRight);



            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                long minutes = (millisUntilFinished / (1000*60)) % 60;
                long seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 ;
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished/1000;

                timeText.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds );

                if (timeLeft <= 10) {
                    playSound(R.raw.clock_beep);
                }

            }
            }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_SPEECH: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                txtText.setText(text.get(0));
                System.out.println(""+text.get(0));
                String spoken = text.get(0);




                if(dbHelp.exists(spoken)){

                     if(dbHelp.isLongest(spoken)){

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have guessed the longest word! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }

                    gameScore = text.get(0).length()*10;
                    scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreView);

                    scoreView.setText(""+gameScore);

                    scHandler = new ScoreHandler(this);
                    scHandler.addScore(new Score(1,gameScore));

                    int cumulativeScore = scHandler.accumulateScores();

                    scoreView.setText(""+cumulativeScore);

                    playSound(R.raw.correct);

                    WordGuessedHandler guessedWord = new WordGuessedHandler(this);

                    guessedWord.addGuessedWord(new Words(1,spoken));




                    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.awesome);
                    myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.fade_in);
                    myFadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.fade_out);


                    img.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
                    img.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation);


               }else{


                     playSound(R.raw.poweng);

                     ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);
                     myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.fade_in);
                     myFadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.fade_out);

                     image.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
                     image.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation);


                }

    }

    }
   }

}

    public String shuffle(String input){
        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(char c:input.toCharArray()){
            characters.add(c);
        }
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());
        while(characters.size()!=0){
            int randPicker = (int)(Math.random()*characters.size());
            output.append(characters.remove(randPicker));

        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());

        return output.toString();

    } 


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent inMain=new Intent(friend.this, MainActivity.class);
        inMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(inMain);
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
          mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
          SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
      super.onStop();

    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // Save the user's current game state
        savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE,gameScore);
        savedInstanceState.putLong(STATE_TIME,timeLeft);
        savedInstanceState.putString(STATE_TIME,randomWord);

        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore state members from saved instance
        gameScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        timeLeft = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_TIME);
        randomWord = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_WORD);
    }


    //sliding menu onChange
    @Override
    public void onContentChanged()
    {
        super.onContentChanged();

        mOpenButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_open );
        mDrawer = (MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer) findViewById( R.id.drawer);

    /*  GridView gridView;
        ArrayList ArrayofName = new ArrayList(); 
    WordHandler db = new WordHandler(this);*/

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);



        txt.setText("Hello There!");


        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        WordGuessedHandler guessed = new WordGuessedHandler(this);

        List <WordGuessed> guessedList = guessed.getAllWordGuessed();

        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(WordGuessed wg:guessedList){

            wordsList.add(wg.getWord());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wordsList);

        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void playSound(int sound) {

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.setVolume(1,1);
        mp.start();

    }


public void removeAll()
{

    ScoreHandler scHandler = new ScoreHandler(this);
    // db.delete(String tableName, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
    // If whereClause is null, it will delete all rows.
    SQLiteDatabase db = scHandler.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is object extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    db.delete("scores_table", null, null);
    db.close();

}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This question answers your question.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Please use the [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) and [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) methods in your main `Activity` to solve this problem. If both method aren't defined, your app will go to the next methods in the lifecycle, which will be `onCreate()` and other methods. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

It is also possible to save your current instance by using [onSaveInstance(Bundle b)](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState) and [onRestoreInstance(Bundle b)](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState)

PS: someone has asked it earlier, and wrote a small example to use the `onSaveInstance` and `onRestoreInstance` (if you want to use it) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744765/how-to-continue-where-the-user-left-off/17745568#17745568).

Comment: I have my onPause and onResume methods.. But what should be its content? I have tried saving the score,time and the current word to the onSaveInstance() but still won't work

Comment: please look to the last link. there is a snippet which would allow you to save the instance. I have also written comments to it to explain it to the questioner.

Comment: @KarelG.. Still doesn' work.. I put the entire code of the activity.. Please help me do this..

Comment: if the activity uses onRestoreInstanceState, onCreate will be ignored. By this, the methods/codes in onCreate won't be initiated. A simple workaround is to put it in an apart method, like "init()" and call it from both onRestoreInstanceState and onCreate. (copy over the content after the first if-else block to the end and put it in the new method)

Comment: Using instance is more complicated than using onPause() I think. If I'll be using the onPause(), what would be it's content? How can I take back the current state of the game using onPause()?

Comment: you are free to use the onPauze/onResume. it works the same way as onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance. The only difference is that when your app got destroyed, its contents won't be saved.

Comment: so you are saying that I'll put the content of the onSaveInstance to the onPause() and the onRestore() to the onResume? Is it what you are trying to tell me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34317/discussion-between-karelg-and-edmund02)