# onDestroy being called

Tags: android, android-activity, background, ondestroy

I can't figure out the onDestroy() behaviour.
My question is: Is there any chance that an activity will be killed without calling it's onDestroy() while not killing the hole app?
I mean, Could it be that I'll get back to my app (to an activity other then the activity that the launcher calls) and be in a situation where one activity was killed without calling it's onDestroy()?

I have a need to know that if I get back from the background to an activity that there is no way some of my activities where killed without it's onDestroy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No i don't think so , when your application get killed because of lack of Memory your whole app process would be killed so in this situation onDestroy() may not be called and your app will back again on your launcher Activity unless you can save your application state on **onPause()** state before your app get killed.

Comment: Can you please look at my question again after my edit? I just want to be sure that I was clear.

Comment: can you be more specific about your question? i can't understand your need on your edit

Comment: It's really as simple as that, Can one activity be killed without it's onDestroy() being called while another activity stay's alive?

Comment: And the other activity stays alive?!

Comment: when your Activity is on and user interact with that it's kill priority is less than other Activities and other apps and usually your Activity doesn't get killed so other Acitivities may get killed without onDestory get called.sometimes Android decide to kill your whole app and it depends on the lack of memory.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Android will kill a least frequently used activity if there is not enough memory is available for the newly started app. Also the back button triggers the onDestroy(). A best bet is to save your app state. Here is an example to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744765/how-to-continue-where-the-user-left-off/17745568#17745568) how to save and restore your current instance.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the API documentation Activity#onDestroy():

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29

And don't forget to call super.onDestroy()